# Making a database backup

Tags: php, mysql

I created two simple PHP scripts to back up a MySQL database, but these are not working as expected. I use my program on a Mac using MAMP and using AMPPS on Windows 7.

Here the two scripts I use to backup the database:

[Message edited]

The First and only code

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="root";
$db="trasporti";
$dbcnx_backup=@mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$password");
mysql_select_db("$db");

$backupFile = '../../t6/backup/' . $db . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.sql';
$command = "mysqldump -h $host -u $user -p $password $db > $backupFile";
system($command, $retval);

echo $command;
var_dump($retval);

if ($retval==0)
{
 echo "BackUP Riuscito!";
}
 else
    {
     echo "BackUP Fallito!";
    }

mysql_close($dbcnx_backup);

?>
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The second example is useless. You should try to fix the first one. Give us the output of `echo $command;` and `var_dump($retval);`.

Comment: If that `connect.php` is opening a DB connection, then that's useless too - you're not using any of PHP's mysql stuff, simply using an external mysql command which would establish its OWN connection anyways, completely independent of PHP's. Of major importance: Is mysqldump in your shell's path?

Comment: What is in `$host`? If its `localhost`, try `127.0.0.1`....

Comment: where do you set up the parameter: $db ? plus, there is no "space" between the "-p" and the "$password"

Comment: I edited the first message with the only "right code"..

this is the output of the echo $command;


 mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p root trasporti > ../../t6/backup/trasporti2012-01-30-12-36-25.sqlint(1) BackUP Fallito!
 

how can i check if mysqldump is in my shell's path and how to fix it?

Comment: You means these lines?

safe_mode Off Off
safe_mode_exec_dir no value no value
safe_mode_gid Off Off
safe_mode_include_dir no value no value

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space after -p.

You can remove all the calls to the mysql_ functions in your code.

Is safe_mode enabled in your PHP configuration? Use phpinfo() to tell, if yes, you might need to [configure PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) properly or turn it off.